# Free remote desktop software for real time screencasting

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am selling desktop-based application, and I want to demo my software to potential clients who are living thousands of miles away from me. I can either fly in and demo to him in person, or I can ask him to see my demonstration remotely.

Is there a free software that I can use to allow him to see my desktop remotely?

I just need a software that

1. he can see what's on my screen and
2. allows us to have real time conversation as I do the demo
3. there is no need for him to remotely control my software.
4. I can record the demo and reuse it later for salesman training purpose

Teamviewer is actually a good choice, but it's *not* free after a while. Also, I'm not sure whether one can have real time conversation using that software

[Youtube screencasting](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/show-dont-tell-3-best-free-screencasting-tools-for-windows/) is actually a good choice, but the problem with this is that I can't let my potential clients see my demo in real time.

Comment: Have you looked at screen-sharing features in Skype or Google Hangouts? Or tried [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) products such as RealVNC or Apple Screen Sharing? If you have done any of that, describe how it did or did not fit your needs.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I've no knowledge of that. Let me look at it first. To help those who stumble on this question, can you make your comment into a proper answer?

Comment: I was asking more to elucidate your needs then actually provide a solution.

Comment: @BasilBourque , that's all I can think of for now

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems as if [join.me](https://www.join.me/) is the right thing.

It's a remote desktop solution. The free edition

- can share screens (but not windows)
- allows VoIP conversations
- even has remote control features
- is limited to 10 participants

Since the free version does not have recording features, combine it with the free [Open broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) (quite powerful, consider some hours of learning) or [Cam Studio](http://camstudio.org/) (quite simple, but also limited). Open Broadcaster would work for streaming itself, but AFAIK, it is missing the conversation feature (has sound only in one direction).

Answer (score 1):

There is something called [any-desk](http://anydesk.com/download) . It is currently free and maintains a good track record. 
Additionally, you can also use [ammyadmin](http://www.ammyy.com/en/downloads.html) another similar software, but free use is limited to 15 hours per month. But you still can get more than that out of it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that software?

Comment: Does AnyDesk support recording out of the box? I could not find that on the feature list.

Comment: Screen recording is not available in either of the application that I shared. Now if you want to use a screen recording you can use Jing. Just select the portion of the screen you want to record and it will pass through. Jing is a free application.